# Проблема с раширением (dll)

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, плагин

Есть некий плагин, который отправляет по сети данные, когда его подгружает основная программа.
Проблема:

1. Когда работает один, все нормально.
2. Когда работают два плагина из разных директорий (или с разными именами, с разными приемниками данных) тоже все нормально.
3. А вот когда основная программа обращается к одному и тому же `plugin.dll`
   данные отправляются только второму, хотя в конструкторах конструируются все объекты задействованных классов.

Comment: Что значит "когда основная программа обращается к одному и тому же 'plugin.dll'...". У вас основное приложение загружает две длл с одинаковым именем, но из разных директорий?

Comment: Если основное приложение загружает две длл с одинаковым именем, но из разных директорий, все работает отлично!
Но если основное приложение загружает две длл с одинаковым именем, но из одной директорий, работает только второй экземпляр.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341010/could-we-have-2-dlls-with-the-same-name-being-loaded-in-one-process

Comment: в общем если вы грузите 2 длл с одинаковым именем из одной директории (хз как вы это делаете), то работать будет только одна из них, и это должна быть первая длл

Comment: я из основного приложения два раза подгужаю один и тот же плагин, а не две разные с одинаковым именем!

Comment: Если вы подгружаете одну и ту же длл, то она будет загружена всего 1 раз, при первой загрузке. При каждой следующей загрузке вы будете получать дескриптор уже загруженной библиотеки

Comment: всем спасибо, я нашел ответ!
есть глобальная переменная 'thePlugin', которой присваивается this в конструкторе, и не важно сколько раз в программе вызывается конструктор класса, переменная 'thePlugin' указывает на адрес последнего экземпляра, и по этому все остальные сконструированные экземпляры остаются не затронутыми ( в том смысле, что с ними приложение взаимодействует через глобальную переменную 'thePlugin').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, я нашел [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/828032/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-dll#comment1321855_828032) (15 май '18 в 11:40)! Есть глобальная переменная 'thePlugin', которой присваивается this в конструкторе, и не важно сколько раз в программе вызывается конструктор класса, переменная 'thePlugin' указывает на адрес последнего экземпляра, и по этому все остальные сконструированные экземпляры остаются не затронутыми ( в том смысле, что с ними приложение взаимодействует через глобальную переменную 'thePlugin').